# Unable to load library 'kernel32'

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting the following exception when I am running an application in Eclipse:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'kernel32':
>   Native library (linux-x86-64/libkernel32.so) not found in resource
>   path
>   (/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar)

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like it is trying to load a Windows only library

Comment: Could you share part of your code? Give more details so people can help you better

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem before, try executing your application through the terminal using the following syntax:

```
java -Djava.library.path= "path_of_your_application" –jar ApplicationJAR.jar
```

I hope that helps. If it doesn't here is are some guidelines on this website, [Tutorial on UnsatisfiedLinkError](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/)

Cheers